# Accord d'adjectifs dans une énumération

Tags: adjectifs, accord, énumération

Je possède exactement deux angles : un angle polaire et un angle azimutal.
Je voudrais les énumérer en sous entendant le mot "angle".
Ma question est : Comment accorder le nom et les adjectifs dans ce cas?

*mes angles polaire et azimutal ?*

*mes angles polaires et azimutaux ?*

*mon angle polaire et azimutal ?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ces adjectifs coordonnés [restent au singulier](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1744) comme dans:

> Les langues française et anglaise.