# Du règne animal et végétal, ou des règnes ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, pluriel

Dans cette phrase :

> Nous évaluons les dégâts subis par les espèces **du règne animal et végétal**.

Quelle est la différence entre :

- *"du règne animal et végétal"*
- *"des règnes animal et végétal"*
- *"des règnes animaux et végétaux"*

D'instinct la seconde forme me semble plus appropriée dans ce contexte mais je ne suis pas certain du sens des deux autres formes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accord d'adjectifs dans une énumération](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23921/accord-dadjectifs-dans-une-%c3%a9num%c3%a9ration)

Comment: @jlliagre Bien que très liée, ma question est-elle vraiment un duplicata ? J'interroge sur le sens de différentes phrases tandis que la question cible cherche à déterminer la phrase pour un sens spécifique. L’œuf et la poule.

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que la version 1 considère le « règne animal et végétal » comme un tout. La version 2 quant à elle considère qu’il y a 1 règne animal et 1 règne végétal, bien distincts mais uniques. La version 3 laisse penser qu’il y a de multiples règnes animaux et de multiple règnes végétaux.

Je pense que dans la plupart des cas la nuance n’est pas si importante car le concept est le même, et si j’avais à choisir une forme je choisirais effectivement la seconde car elle me paraît la plus appropriée scientifiquement et gramaticalement. La forme 1 par contre me semble sonner mieux à l’oreille et sera je pense souvent comprise comme la forme 2, comme si on disait « du règne animal et (du règne) végétal ».

Answer (score 1):

*Animal* et *végétal* sont ici des adjectifs qui devraient s'accorder avec *règnes*. La forme à priori attendue est donc :

> Nous évaluons les dégâts subis par les espèces des règnes animaux et végétaux.

On rencontre cependant beaucoup de *des règnes animal et végétal*.

L'absence d'accord est elle aussi correcte, et même celle à retenir dans ce cas précis puisqu'il n'y a qu'un seul règne animal et un seul règne végétal :

http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1744

Je serais plus circonspect avec la première proposition car il s'agit de deux règnes distincts.