# Accord du nom avec deux adjectifs

Tags: grammaire, accord

J'ai un doute sur la simplification du groupe suivant:

> Un chemin entre un état initial et un état final

Pour ne pas répéter "état", je suis tenté d'écrire:

> Un chemin entre des états initiaux et finaux

Cependant, maintenant les adjectifs sont au pluriel alors qu'ils ne désignent chacun qu'un état. J'ai essayé de combiner les deux groupes précédents mais le résultat est à première vue faux.

> Un chemin entre des états initial et final

Quelle est la simplification correcte?

Comment: *Un chemin entre des états initial et final* : duplicate of [Accord d'adjectifs dans une énumération](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23921/accord-dadjectifs-dans-une-%c3%a9num%c3%a9ration)

Comment: J'aimerais un minumum d'explication autant que la réponse elle-même.

Comment: Il n'y a qu'un état initial et qu'un état final, donc pas de pluriel possible. Il y a deux états, donc pluriel. Le [lien vers l'OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1744) dans la réponse à l'autre question donne plus de détails.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!