# One brother and one sister - siblings expressed in French

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, formulation-idiomatique

I have a story, translated from English into French, concerning a brother and his sister, who embark on a series of adventures. In the English original, the word "siblings" is used to refer to just the two people - they are indeed siblings. When I received the French version it had been translated as "les frères et sœurs" implying (to me as a native English speaker) multiple siblings of both genders, i.e. at least two brothers and two sisters. I have had a suggestion that "les frère et sœur" would be better, the plural "les" indicating more than one person but "frère et sœur" making it plain that there was only one of each gender. I would be grateful for any comments from native French speakers, please.

Comment: *Les* must be followed by plural nouns, so what you are suggesting is impossible.You are not giving enough context but  *le frère et la sœur*  might be a translation for "siblings" here. Just *frère et sœur* (no definite article) might at times be possible but there again it depends on the context of each sentence.

Comment: @None *Frère et sœur* **is** a plural.

Comment: @Alan can you post the complete sentence? To see if *les frère et sœur* could fit.

Comment: *Fratrie*, defined in some places as *ensemble des frères et sœurs, dans une famille*,  is probably the most literal translation, but it appears somewhat ambiguous in this context (one brother and one sister), and it seems to have a bias towards male siblings, translatable as a *brotherhood*.

Comment: Note that if this is used extensively in the story, given how much longer "les frère et soeur" or "le frère et la soeur" are compared to "the siblings" you may want to finds alternatives here and there, like "les enfants", "la paire", "le duo", "les deux jeunes", "les deux adolescents" (depending on their actual age of course)... Requires a lot more editing than juste search-and-replace, but it may make the result a lot more palatable, depending on the frequency of the expression.

Answer (score 20):

As you noticed, ***les frères et sœurs*** is misleading so shouldn't be used in that case.

***Les*** followed by coordinated singulars is common with adjectives (see ***[les langues française et anglaise](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23921/accord-dadjectifs-dans-une-%C3%A9num%C3%A9ration/23922#23922)***) and with adjectives used as nouns like in ***Les premier, deuxième et troisième sont attendus sur le podium***.

With nouns, if you don't want to risk surprising your readers, you might avoid the issue and just use ***le frère et la sœur*** as suggested by None in a [comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54317/one-brother-and-one-sister-siblings-expressed-in-french/54318#comment116827_54317) (or alternatives suggested by [@jcaron](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54317/one-brother-and-one-sister-siblings-expressed-in-french/54318#comment116862_54317) and [@Eric](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/54321/1109)) but nothing forbids to write ***les frère et sœur*** which is the logical way.

e.g. from the French [Code Civil](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000006070721/LEGISCTA000006150083/) (bold mine in all quotes):

> ***Les père et mère** exercent en commun l'autorité parentale. L'autorité parentale est exercée conjointement dans le cas prévu à l'article 342-11.*

This case is discussed in *Le bon usage*:

> *Dans le cas, relativement rare (cf. § 576, a), où un seul déterminant sert pour plusieurs noms, l'accord se fait comme pour
> l'épithète : le déterminant se met d'ordinaire au pluriel ; le
> genre est celui des noms, si ceux-ci ont le même genre ; sinon,
> le déterminant est au masculin.
> **TES père et mère** honoreras (version traditionnelle du Décalogue). — On
> lui a demandé **SES nom**, prénoms et qualités. — Tous les us et coutumes.
>
> [...]
>
> Les [le] ou [le], en liaison [lez] ou [lez], avec un nom pluriel, quel
> que soit le genre : LES parents. LES mères. LES enfants. — Parfois avec plusieurs noms singuliers (§ 577, b) : **LES père et mère**.*
>
> Grevisse et Goose, *Le bon usage, 14e édition*, 2008.

The quote is possibly from Buffon:

> *Mais des gens, qui se croient bien au fait des intentions des oiseaux, assurent que c’est par une sage défiance que **les père et mère** suspendent ainsi leur nid, et pour mettre la couvée en sûreté contre certains animaux terrestres, et surtout contre les serpents.*
>
> Buffon, [Histoire naturelle des oiseaux](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/%C5%92uvres_compl%C3%A8tes_de_Buffon,_%C3%A9d._Lanessan/Histoire_naturelle_des_oiseaux/Le_troupiale), 1770.

Québec French is no exception:

> *Responsabilité civile **des père et mère** pour le préjudice causé, soit par leurs fautes personnelles comme titulaires de l'autorité parentale ou comme tuteurs, soit par le fait ou la faute de leur enfant mineur non émancipé, soit du fait d'un bien de cet enfant dont ils ont la garde comme tuteurs.*
>
> *[Dictionnaire encyclopédique du Droit québécois](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/26551236/responsabilite-des-pere-et-mere)*, Gaudet

Modern examples can also be found:

> *Eux, **les fils et fille** en manque de mère, n'ont pas imaginé la quitter davantage que l'espace d'une douche chaude.*
>
> [Le Figaro](https://www.lefigaro.fr/international/2008/08/30/01003-20080830ARTFIG00185-premier-ete-de-liberte-pour-ingrid-betancourt-.php), 30 août 2008

> *Dans cette interview qualifiée d’« intimiste » par nos confrères du service public, Philippe et Mathilde évoquent leurs fiançailles et leur mariage mais aussi leur vie de couple, eux **les roi et reine** du pays, ainsi que leur vie de famille, eux les parents de quatre enfants.*
>
> [SoirMag](https://soirmag.lesoir.be/262646/article/2019-11-25/le-roi-philippe-et-la-reine-mathilde-accordent-un-entretien-inedit-la-rtbf-pour) (Belgique), 2019

> *Place Carmin
>
> **Les roi et reine** de la Main, Mélanie Blanchette et le chef François Nadon accompagnés de leur équipe de feu (Bouillon Bilk et Cadet) ont ouvert dans le Vieux-Montréal le très beau restaurant Place Carmin.*
>
> [Tastet.ca](https://tastet.ca/listes/salle-privee-evenement-montreal/) (Québec), 2023

> *Le Rocher de Monaco célèbre le 9ème anniversaire des jumeaux princiers, Jacques et Gabriella, ce dimanche 10 décembre 2023. Ces jeunes membres de la famille royale, qui sont **les fils et fille** du Prince Albert et de la Princesse Charlène, attirent l’attention par leur beauté et leur prestance.*
>
> [Peopletv.fr](https://peopletv.fr/anniversaire-royal-charlene-et-albert-de-monaco-fetent-jacques-et-gabriella-avec-une-photo-touchante/), 2023

Comment: Thank you very much. The quotation from the Code Civil seems to clinch it, so I will edit (in fact I have already edited) the French version of my story to read "les frère et sœur" as a translation of "the siblings" throughout.

Comment: The thing is, legalese doesn't really follow the same rules as more usual texts. It is often heavy and convoluted. Personally, I see a typo.

Comment: Amazing answer with great examples. Thank you!

Comment: Related (Canada): https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdqyO.jpg

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes! Big picture :-)

Answer (score 8):

As a French native speaker from France, "les frère et sœur" sounds fine to me. I have one brother and one sister, and it was common for my parents to talk to me about "tes frère et sœur" (your brother and sister) when referring to my siblings. I do the same when talking to my own children these days.

That said, it depends on the context and it would be nice to know the original sentence, as a commenter suggested.

Assuming it was "The Smith siblings leave for an adventure" (would that be the best wording, I wonder), I am not sure the best translation would be "Les frère et sœur Smith partent à l'aventure". Although grammatically correct, the reader is somewhat surprised not to see a plural after "les". An alternative might be "Les enfants Smith partent à l'aventure", which feels more natural to me here.

Answer (score -1):

> les frère et sœur

Is just terrible. I'm a native french speaker (Quebec) and all I can see is a grammatical error. I don't see how anyone would find it acceptable.

> le frère et la sœur

That works.

> les frères et sœurs

That works too, even if it is a bit long. It doesn't convey multiple sisters and brothers. If there were multiple of each, it would be:

> les frères et les sœurs

Comment: It may be that this (admittedly edge case) is not standard in Québec.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Not less standard in Québec: ***Les roi et reine** de la Main, Mélanie Blanchette et le chef François Nadon accompagnés de leur équipe de feu (Bouillon Bilk et Cadet) ont ouvert dans le Vieux-Montréal le très beau restaurant Place Carmin.*  [tastet.ca](https://tastet.ca/listes/salle-privee-evenement-montreal/)